# Have an (ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), ...)) after concating two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm concatenating two dataframes with concat() function

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```

Concat is OK, but after this my function return an error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

function is the following:

```
#function is replacing NaN values with a value from previous row
def fill_nan_column(df, column_name):
    counter = 0
    for row in df[column_name]:
        if pd.isnull(df.loc[counter,column_name]): #if value == NaN return True
            df.loc[counter, column_name] = df.loc[counter - 1,column_name]
        counter += 1
```

Before concatenation my function worked fine.

Also if I concat two dataframe with pd.append() everything is fine too. Like this:

```
df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Can't understand what the magic happens after concat() in my dataframe

Comment: common indexes in df1 & df2 result in `.loc` to choose more than 1 row in `df.loc[counter, name]`, and you get a Series back not a scalar, whose nullness is again a Series whose truth value as implicitly queried by the if statement is ambigous hence the error. Perhaps pass `ignore_index=True` to concat as well. But better yet, there is `ffill` so your function is equivalent to `df[column_name] = df[column_name].ffill()` at first glance.

Comment: `ignore_index=True` helps. The problem was in double index values, you were right. thanks